# How to put page break in dompdf with code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

My code is working when I tried to run it, it goes well. It shows the complete records. But when I convert it to dompdf, it does not break and cut some of the records. I cannot show you the sample pics because i need at least 10 reputations. Help me.

Here is the code

```
//PRINT TO PDF 
$html = $this->output->get_output(); 
//Load Library 
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen'); 
//Convert to PDF 
$pdf = "Billing-" . $data['reference_number']; 
$this->dompdf->load_html($html); 
$this->dompdf->render(); 
$this->dompdf->stream($pdf . ".pdf", array('Attachment' => 0));
```

Comment: Maybe you can show the code that you have right now?

Comment: you need to add page breaks to your html

Comment: i already tried it. that after;always whatever. But it turned out, it prints the whole records BUT in another page. Page 1 has plenty of space

Comment: html to pdf is always tricky, there's no real relationship between the two. perhaps try another pdf creator library

Comment: upload image to cloud storage and provide link.(Use google drive and share the link)

Comment: Add a sample of your HTML so we can see why it's not working. There are some instances where dompdf will pull an element to the next page on page break.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
//PRINT TO PDF 
$html = $this->output->get_output(); 
//Load Library 
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen'); 
//Convert to PDF 
$pdf = "Billing-" . $data['reference_number']; 
$this->dompdf->load_html($html); 
$this->dompdf->render(); 
$this->dompdf->stream($pdf . ".pdf", array('Attachment' => 0));exit;
```